# Bug - TextDecoration Strikethrough not working on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a label where I want strikethrough and a lineheight of 1.5
This works fine with Android, but strikethrough does not work on iOS when LineHeight is also set.

Steps to Reproduce

```
 - Create new Xamarin.Forms project.
 - Add label with textdecoration=strikethrough 
 - Test strikethrough
 - Run emulator
```

Expected Behavior

- Display of label with Strikethrough text

Actual Behavior

- Text displayed normally, not with Strikethrough on iOS (Android works
  fine)

Comment: Is this happening on devices as well? Or just simulators?

Comment: There are a few open issues revolving around iOS and strikethrough, i.e. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11829

Comment: It happens in both device and simulator. And yes thanks for sharing github link @SushiHangover but is there any work around for it?

Comment: It seems that there is no fix or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with a label custom renderer...

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace YourApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<TextDecorations, NSString> attributeNames =
            new Dictionary<TextDecorations, NSString> {
                {
                    TextDecorations.Underline,
                    UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle },
                {
                    TextDecorations.Strikethrough,
                    UIStringAttributeKey.StrikethroughStyle
                }
            };

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (sender is Label label &&
                label.FormattedText?.Spans.ToList() is List<Span> spans)
            {
                var aux = new NSMutableAttributedString(Control.AttributedText);
                spans.ForEach(span => {
                    if (attributeNames.TryGetValue(span.TextDecorations,
                        out var attributeName))
                    {
                        var startIndex = Control.Text.IndexOf(span.Text);
                        aux.AddAttribute(
                            attributeName,
                            new NSNumber(1),
                            new NSRange(startIndex, span.Text.Length));
                    }
                });
                Control.AttributedText = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for Underline and Strikethrough.